# How to install Apache Cassandra on CentOS 7?

Tags: cassandra

Cassandra installation documentation mentions installation from a tarball or as a Debian package. Is there a way to install it using yum, now that DataStax does not provides the distribution?

Comment: possibly [HowtoForge.com: Step 2 - Installing Cassandra](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-apache-cassandra-on-centos-7/) ?

Answer (score 1):

CentOS uses RPM as package format as far as I can remember. So look on http://cassandra.apache.org/download/:

Installation from RPM packages

For the  specify the major version number, without dot, and with an appended x. The latest  is 311x. For older releases, the  can be one of 30x, 22x, or 21x.

(Not all versions of Apache Cassandra are available, since building RPMs is a recent addition to the project.)

Add the Apache repository of Cassandra to /etc/yum.repos.d/cassandra.repo, for example for the latest 3.11 version:

```
[cassandra]
name=Apache Cassandra
baseurl=https://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/redhat/311x/
gpgcheck=1
repo_gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/KEYS
```

Install Cassandra, accepting the gpg key import prompts:

```
sudo yum install cassandra
```

Start Cassandra (will not start automatically):

```
service cassandra start
```

Systemd based distributions may require to run systemctl daemon-reload once to make Cassandra available as a systemd service. This should happen automatically by running the command above.

Make Cassandra start automatically after reboot:

```
chkconfig cassandra on
```

Please note that official RPMs for Apache Cassandra only have been available recently and are not tested thoroughly on all platforms yet. We appreciate your feedback and support and ask you to post details on any issues in the corresponding Jira ticket.